# How do I fix my code so it runs correctly, it keeps telling me I have Error Code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to complete this multi-query assignment but cannot figure out why I keep getting this error code (Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY E.EventDate ASC' at line 3). Below is my code

```
SELECT C.ClientID, C.ClientName, EC.ClientID, EC.EventCode, E.EventCode, E.EventName, E.EventDate, NT.EventCode, T.EventCode
FROM Non_Ticketed_Events AS NT
 LEFT JOIN Events AS E
 LEFT JOIN Ticketed_Events AS T
 LEFT JOIN Client AS C
 LEFT JOIN Event_Contact AS EC
   ON NT.EventCode = E.EventCode
   AND T.EventCode = E.EventCode
   AND E.EventCode = EC.EventCode
   AND EC.ClientID = C.ClientID
ORDER BY E.EventDate ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Each join condition must be place to the specific ON clause

```
SELECT C.ClientID
, C.ClientName
, EC.ClientID
, EC.EventCode
, E.EventCode
, E.EventName
, E.EventDate
, NT.EventCode
, T.EventCode
FROM Non_Ticketed_Events NT 
LEFT JOIN Events  E  ON NT.EventCode = E.EventCode
LEFT JOIN Ticketed_Events  T  ON T.EventCode = E.EventCode
LEFT JOIN Client  C ON EC.ClientID = C.ClientID
LEFT JOIN Event_Contact  EC ON E.EventCode = EC.EventCode
ORDER BY E.EventDate ASC;
```

Comment: I am still running into the Error 1064 LEFT JOIN Ticketed_Events AS T T.EventCode = E.EventCode this line is producing an error.

Comment: answer  updated .. missing ON clause in some join